# Minimizing this error function, using NumPy

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, math, mathematical-optimization

**Background**

I've been working for some time on attempting to solve the (notoriously painful) Time Difference of Arrival (TDoA) multi-lateration problem, in `3-dimensions` and using `4` nodes. If you're unfamiliar with the problem, it is to determine the coordinates of some signal source `(X,Y,Z)`, given the coordinates of `n` nodes, the time of arrival of the signal at each node, and the velocity of the signal `v`.

My solution is as follows:

For each node, we write `(X-x_i)**2 + (Y-y_i)**2 + (Z-z_i)**2 = (v(t_i - T)**2`

Where `(x_i, y_i, z_i)` are the coordinates of the `ith` node, and `T` is the time of emission.

We have now `4` equations in `4` unknowns. Four nodes are obviously insufficient. We *could* try to solve this system directly, however that seems next to impossible given the highly nonlinear nature of the problem (and, indeed, I've tried *many* direct techniques... and failed). *Instead*, we simplify this to a linear problem by considering all `i/j` possibilities, subtracting equation `i` from equation `j`. We obtain `(n(n-1))/2` `=6` equations of the form:

`2*(x_j - x_i)*X + 2*(y_j - y_i)*Y + 2*(z_j - z_i)*Z + 2 * v**2 * (t_i - t_j) = v**2 ( t_i**2 - t_j**2) + (x_j**2 + y_j**2 + z_j**2) - (x_i**2 + y_i**2 + z_i**2)`

Which look like `Xv_1 + Y_v2 + Z_v3 + T_v4 = b`. We try now to apply standard linear least squares, where the solution is the matrix vector `x` in `A^T Ax = A^T b`. Unfortunately, if you were to try feeding this into any standard linear least squares algorithm, it'll choke up. So, what do we do now?

...

The time of arrival of the signal at node `i` is given (of course) by:

`sqrt( (X-x_i)**2 + (Y-y_i)**2 + (Z-z_i)**2 ) / v`

This equation implies that the time of arrival, `T`, is `0`. If we have that `T = 0`, we can drop the `T` column in matrix `A` and the problem is greatly simplified. Indeed, `NumPy's` `linalg.lstsq()` gives a surprisingly accurate & precise result.

...

So, what I do is *normalize* the input times by subtracting from each equation the earliest time. All I have to do then is determine the `dt` that I can add to each time such that the residual of summed squared error for the point found by linear least squares is minimized.

I define the error for some `dt` to be the squared difference between the arrival time for the point predicted by feeding the `input times` + `dt` to the least squares algorithm, minus the input time (normalized), summed over all `4` nodes.

```
for node, time in nodes, times:
    error += ( (sqrt( (X-x_i)**2 + (Y-y_i)**2 + (Z-z_i)**2 ) / v) - time) ** 2
```

**My problem:**

I was able to do this somewhat satisfactorily by using brute-force. I started at `dt = 0`, and moved by some step up to some maximum # of iterations *OR* until some minimum RSS error is reached, and that was the `dt` I added to the normalized times to obtain a solution. The resulting solutions were very accurate and precise, but quite slow.

In practice, I'd like to be able to solve this in *real* time, and therefore a far **faster** solution will be needed. I began with the assumption that the error function (that is, `dt` vs `error` as defined above) would be highly nonlinear-- offhand, this made sense to me.

Since I don't have an actual, mathematical function, I can automatically rule out methods that require differentiation (e.g. `Newton-Raphson`). The error function will always be positive, so I can rule out `bisection`, etc. Instead, I try a simple approximation search. Unfortunately, that failed miserably. I then tried Tabu search, followed by a genetic algorithm, and several others. They all failed horribly.

So, I decided to do some investigating. As it turns out the plot of the error function vs dt looks a bit like a square root, only shifted right depending upon the distance from the nodes that the signal source is:

[image]
[image]

**Where `dt` is on horizontal axis, error on vertical axis**

And, in hindsight, *of course it does!*. I defined the error function to involve square roots so, at least to me, this seems reasonable.

**What to do?**

So, my issue now is, how do I determine the `dt` corresponding to the minimum of the error function?

My first (very crude) attempt was to get some points on the error graph (as above), fit it using `numpy.polyfit`, then feed the results to `numpy.root`. That root corresponds to the `dt`. Unfortunately, this failed, too. I tried fitting with various `degrees`, and also with various points, up to a ridiculous number of points such that I may as well just use brute-force.

**How can I determine the `dt` corresponding to the minimum of this error function?**

Since we're dealing with high velocities (radio signals), it's important that the results be *precise* and *accurate*, as minor variances in `dt` can throw off the resulting point.

I'm sure that there's some infinitely simpler approach buried in what I'm doing here however, ignoring everything else, how do I find `dt`?

**My requirements:**

1. Speed is of utmost importance
2. I have access only to pure `Python` and `NumPy` in the environment where this will be run

**EDIT:**

Here's my code. Admittedly, a bit messy. Here, I'm using the `polyfit` technique. It will "simulate" a source for you, and compare results:

```
from numpy import poly1d, linspace, set_printoptions, array, linalg, triu_indices, roots, polyfit
from dataclasses import dataclass
from random import randrange
import math

@dataclass
class Vertexer:

    receivers: list

    # Defaults
    c = 299792

    # Receivers:
    # [x_1, y_1, z_1]
    # [x_2, y_2, z_2]
    # [x_3, y_3, z_3]

    # Solved:
    # [x, y, z]

    def error(self, dt, times):
        solved = self.linear([time + dt for time in times])

        error = 0
        for time, receiver in zip(times, self.receivers):
            error += ((math.sqrt( (solved[0] - receiver[0])**2 + 
                (solved[1] - receiver[1])**2 +
                (solved[2] - receiver[2])**2 ) / c ) - time)**2

        return error

    def linear(self, times):
        X = array(self.receivers)
        t = array(times)

        x, y, z = X.T   
        i, j = triu_indices(len(x), 1)

        A = 2 * (X[i] - X[j])
        b = self.c**2 * (t[j]**2 - t[i]**2) + (X[i]**2).sum(1) - (X[j]**2).sum(1)

        solved, residuals, rank, s = linalg.lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)

        return(solved)

    def find(self, times):
        # Normalize times
        times = [time - min(times) for time in times]
        
        # Fit the error function

        y = []
        x = []
        dt = 1E-10
        for i in range(50000):
            x.append(self.error(dt * i, times))
            y.append(dt * i)    

        p = polyfit(array(x), array(y), 2)
        r = roots(p)
        
        return(self.linear([time + r for time in times]))




# SIMPLE CODE FOR SIMULATING A SIGNAL

# Pick nodes to be at random locations
x_1 = randrange(10); y_1 = randrange(10); z_1 = randrange(10)
x_2 = randrange(10); y_2 = randrange(10); z_2 = randrange(10)
x_3 = randrange(10); y_3 = randrange(10); z_3 = randrange(10)
x_4 = randrange(10); y_4 = randrange(10); z_4 = randrange(10)

# Pick source to be at random location
x = randrange(1000); y = randrange(1000); z = randrange(1000)

# Set velocity
c = 299792 # km/ns

# Generate simulated source
t_1 = math.sqrt( (x - x_1)**2 + (y - y_1)**2 + (z - z_1)**2 ) / c
t_2 = math.sqrt( (x - x_2)**2 + (y - y_2)**2 + (z - z_2)**2 ) / c
t_3 = math.sqrt( (x - x_3)**2 + (y - y_3)**2 + (z - z_3)**2 ) / c
t_4 = math.sqrt( (x - x_4)**2 + (y - y_4)**2 + (z - z_4)**2 ) / c

print('Actual:', x, y, z)

myVertexer = Vertexer([[x_1, y_1, z_1],[x_2, y_2, z_2],[x_3, y_3, z_3],[x_4, y_4, z_4]])
solution = myVertexer.find([t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4])
print(solution)
```

Comment: Great explanation of the problem. Is it possible for you to provide a sample data and your relevant code?

Comment: @Amit Absolutely! One moment, I'll update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the Bancroft method applies to this problem? Here's a pure NumPy implementation.

```
# Implementation of the Bancroft method, following
# https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Bancroft_Method
M = np.diag([1, 1, 1, -1])


def lorentz_inner(v, w):
    return np.sum(v * (w @ M), axis=-1)


B = np.array(
    [
        [x_1, y_1, z_1, c * t_1],
        [x_2, y_2, z_2, c * t_2],
        [x_3, y_3, z_3, c * t_3],
        [x_4, y_4, z_4, c * t_4],
    ]
)
one = np.ones(4)
a = 0.5 * lorentz_inner(B, B)
B_inv_one = np.linalg.solve(B, one)
B_inv_a = np.linalg.solve(B, a)
for Lambda in np.roots(
    [
        lorentz_inner(B_inv_one, B_inv_one),
        2 * (lorentz_inner(B_inv_one, B_inv_a) - 1),
        lorentz_inner(B_inv_a, B_inv_a),
    ]
):
    x, y, z, c_t = M @ np.linalg.solve(B, Lambda * one + a)
    print("Candidate:", x, y, z, c_t / c)
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer might have mistakes (glaring) as I had not heard the TDOA term before this afternoon. Please double check if the method is right.

I could not find solution to your original problem of finding dt corresponding to the minimum error. My answer also deviates from the requirement that other than numpy no third party library had to be used (I used Sympy and largely used the code from [here](https://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonSolveEquations)). However I am still posting this thinking that somebody someday might find it useful if all one is interested in ... is to find X,Y,Z of the source emitter. This method also does not take into account real-life situations where white noise or errors might be present or curvature of the earth and other complications.

Your initial test conditions are as below.

```py
from random import randrange
import math

# SIMPLE CODE FOR SIMULATING A SIGNAL

# Pick nodes to be at random locations
x_1 = randrange(10); y_1 = randrange(10); z_1 = randrange(10)
x_2 = randrange(10); y_2 = randrange(10); z_2 = randrange(10)
x_3 = randrange(10); y_3 = randrange(10); z_3 = randrange(10)
x_4 = randrange(10); y_4 = randrange(10); z_4 = randrange(10)

# Pick source to be at random location
x = randrange(1000); y = randrange(1000); z = randrange(1000)

# Set velocity
c = 299792 # km/ns

# Generate simulated source
t_1 = math.sqrt( (x - x_1)**2 + (y - y_1)**2 + (z - z_1)**2 ) / c
t_2 = math.sqrt( (x - x_2)**2 + (y - y_2)**2 + (z - z_2)**2 ) / c
t_3 = math.sqrt( (x - x_3)**2 + (y - y_3)**2 + (z - z_3)**2 ) / c
t_4 = math.sqrt( (x - x_4)**2 + (y - y_4)**2 + (z - z_4)**2 ) / c

print('Actual:', x, y, z)
```

My solution is as below.

```py
import sympy as sym
X,Y,Z = sym.symbols('X,Y,Z', real=True)
f = sym.Eq((x_1 - X)**2 +(y_1 - Y)**2 + (z_1 - Z)**2 , (c*t_1)**2)
g = sym.Eq((x_2 - X)**2 +(y_2 - Y)**2 + (z_2 - Z)**2 , (c*t_2)**2)
h = sym.Eq((x_3 - X)**2 +(y_3 - Y)**2 + (z_3 - Z)**2 , (c*t_3)**2)
i = sym.Eq((x_4 - X)**2 +(y_4 - Y)**2 + (z_4 - Z)**2 , (c*t_4)**2)

print("Solved coordinates are ", sym.solve([f,g,h,i],X,Y,Z))
```

print statement from your initial condition gave.

```py
Actual: 111 553 110
```

and the solution that almost instantly came out was

```py
Solved coordinates are  [(111.000000000000, 553.000000000000, 110.000000000000)]
```

Sorry again if something is totally amiss.