# Solving this system of nonlinear equations with Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math, physics, mathematical-optimization

**Problem.**

Consider the following problem: An experiment consists of three receivers, `i,j` and `k`, with known coordinates `(xi,yi,zi), (xj,yi...` in 3D space. A stationary transmitter, with unknown coordinates `(x,y,z)`, emits a signal with known velocity `v`. The time of arrival of this signal at each receiver is recorded, giving `ti,tj,tk`. The signal emission time, `t`, is unknown.

**Using only the coordinates of the receivers and the signal arrival times, I wish to determine the location of the transmitter.**

---

In general, to solve for the coordinates of such a transmitter in `N`-dimensional space, `N+1` receivers are required. Hence, in this case, a single, unique solution is unobtainable. A *small* number of finite solutions should be obtainable via numerical methods, however.

We may write the following system of equations to model the problem:

```
Sqrt[(x-xi)^2 + (y-yi)^2 + (z-zi)^2] + s(tj-ti) = Sqrt[(x-xj)^2 + (y-yj)^2 + (z-zj)^2]
Sqrt[(x-xj)^2 + (y-yj)^2 + (z-zj)^2] + s(tk-tj) = Sqrt[(x-xk)^2 + (y-yk)^2 + (z-zk)^2]
Sqrt[(x-xi)^2 + (y-yi)^2 + (z-zi)^2] + s(tk-ti) = Sqrt[(x-xk)^2 + (y-yk)^2 + (z-zk)^2]
```

Each equation gives a *hyperboloid*. Under ideal conditions, these three hyperboloids will intersect at *precisely* two points— one being the "true" solution, and the other being a reflection of that solution about the plane defined by the three receivers. In practice, given sufficiently accurate measurements, numerical solvers should be able to approximate these points of intersection.

**My goal is to determine both solutions. Although it is impossible to determine which is the "true" transmitter location, for my purposes this will be sufficient.**

---

**Implementation.**

I wish to implement a solution in `Python`. I'm not terribly familiar with `NumPy` or `SciPy`, however I've done a fair bit of work in `SymPy`, so I began there.

`SymPy` offers a variety of solvers, most of which focus on obtaining solutions symbolically. Not surprisingly, `solve()` and the like failed to find a solution, even under simulated "ideal" conditions (picking a random point, calculating the time taken for a signal originating from that point to arrive at each receiver, and feeding this to the algorithm).

`SymPy` also offers a numerical solver, `nsolve()`. I gave this a go, using the approach given below, however (not surpisingly) I got the error `ZeroDivisionError: Matrix is numerically singular`.

```
f = sym.Eq(sym.sqrt((x - x_i)**2 + (y - y_i)**2 + (z - z_i)**2) - sym.sqrt((x - x_j)**2 + (y - y_j)**2 + (z - z_j)**2), D_ij)
g = sym.Eq(sym.sqrt((x - x_i)**2 + (y - y_i)**2 + (z - z_i)**2) - sym.sqrt((x - x_k)**2 + (y - y_k)**2 + (z - z_k)**2), D_ik)
h = sym.Eq(sym.sqrt((x - x_j)**2 + (y - y_j)**2 + (z - z_j)**2) - sym.sqrt((x - x_k)**2 + (y - y_k)**2 + (z - z_k)**2), D_jk)
 
print("Soln. ", sym.nsolve((f,g,h),(x,y,z), (1,1,1)))
```

As I understand it, `nsolve()` relies on "matrix" techniques. A singular matrix is one which may not be inverted (or, equivalently, which has determinant zero), hence `SymPy` is unable to solve the system in question.

My understanding of matrices and nonlinear system solving techniques is a bit lacking, however my understanding is that a singular matrix occurs when there are *infinitely many solutions, no solutions, or more than one solution*. Given that I know there to be exactly two solutions, I believe this is the issue.

---

What Python solvers are available can be used so solve a nonlinear system with multiple solutions? Or, alternatively, is there a way to modify this such that it is digestible by `SymPy`?

Browsing the `Numpy` and `SciPy` docs, it seems that their solvers are effectively identical to what `SymPy` offers.

---

The (crude) test code mentioned below:

```
from random import randrange
import math

# SIMPLE CODE FOR SIMULATING A SIGNAL

# Set range
N=10
P=100

# Pick nodes to be at random locations
x_1 = randrange(N); y_1 = randrange(N); z_1 = randrange(N)
x_2 = randrange(N); y_2 = randrange(N); z_2 = randrange(N)
x_3 = randrange(N); y_3 = randrange(N); z_3 = randrange(N)

# Pick source to be at random location
x = randrange(P); y = randrange(P); z = randrange(P)

# Set velocity
c = 299792 # km/ns

# Generate simulated source
t_1 = math.sqrt( (x - x_1)**2 + (y - y_1)**2 + (z - z_1)**2 ) / c
t_2 = math.sqrt( (x - x_2)**2 + (y - y_2)**2 + (z - z_2)**2 ) / c
t_3 = math.sqrt( (x - x_3)**2 + (y - y_3)**2 + (z - z_3)**2 ) / c

# Normalize times to remove information about 'true' emission time
earliest = min(t_1, t_2, t_3)
t_1 = t_1 - earliest; t_2 = t2 - earliest; t_3 = t_3 = earliest
```

Comment: Did you try other initial values for `(x, y, z)` than `(1, 1, 1)`?

Comment: [Same question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436017/minimizing-this-error-function-using-numpy/65441063#65441063)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Similar, but not the same. That question and its solutions are valid for 3 receivers in 2D, or 4 receivers in 3D. Here, I wish to determine the two possible solutions for 3 receivers in 3D which, unfortunately, requires a different approach. Additionally, this is perhaps more about solvers than the solution itself (I believe I know, generally, how to model and approach the problem mathematically... solving that with software is the issue)--- Also, it seems I forgot to accept your answer there, which was quite helpful. Just did.

Comment: Ah, we can derive the third equation by summing the first two and subtracting the distance term for j. So there's only two independent equations and three unknowns, and the solution space in general will be 1D.

Comment: Concretely, suppose that the three receivers are located at the vertices of an equilateral triangle. If ti = tj = tk, then all we know is that the transmitter is on the line perpendicular to the plane containing the triangle and passing through the center of the triangle.

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: @joni Sure! What I'm doing now is to use an (admittedly somewhat crude) `Python` script to generate a random point in `3D` space, then calculate the time taken for light to travel from that point to each of three randomly generated points representing the receivers. I then normalize those times to remove information about the true emission time, and pass them to the algorithm. I've added that code to the post. I have some real-life data as well. I'll try to put it in a useful format and post that soon, as well.